# How to break out of nested loop in C

Tags: loops, break

How can I break out of nested loops in C without using goto, if I have "while" in "while" for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can put both loops into a function the *return* statement could be used. Else the outer loop needs a further condition.